# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Screen Display crashing

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Here are the specs on my desktop computer:

I5 processor 
24 GB Ram 
256GB SSD 
NVIDIA GTX Titan X

I just migrated this system over from Windows 7 64 bit to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bit, to match my laptop. This issue is that I have 3 monitors connected to my desktop and every time I click on Screen Display in System Settings the System Settings windows just closes. The first couple of times it gave me a crash error and the window just started to close. I have clicked on other items in the System Settings window and they open fine, it is just this that is giving me issues.

I tried changing the driver under Additional Drivers in the Software & Updates window from "Using X.Org..." to "Using NVIDIA binary driver..." (the one that said tested at the end of it) and when I rebooted the computer all 3 screens went to sleep and I was unable to do anything with them (I was able to get into safe graphics mode and change it back). I also tried downloading the Linux driver 64 bit version from the NVIDIA site itself, but that seemed to save a .run file and I tried to run it in a terminal window with no luck, not sure what to do with it.

I also have installed the NVIDIA X Server Settings, but do not seem to see anything in there regarding my card or settings.  The only two items listed on the left hand side are:

"Application Profiles"
"nvidia-settings Configuration"

As well I installed xfce4-display-settings and ran xfce4-display-settings -m and in there changed my screen settings, in the window that opened, to the way that I wanted, but it did not seem to make any difference.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo lshw`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have.  also a copy of your `monitors.xml` pasted to http://paste.ubuntu.com would be nice. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using very new GPU hardware, it is recommended to use the very latest stable drivers.

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting TITAN X from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the short-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.