# Proprietary nvidia drivers for TitanX screen refresh problems (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, proprietary

[How screen looks like with proprietary drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuIoD.jpg)

Hi all,
 I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new machine.
 (Machine specs: Nvidia Titan X, dual Xeon E5-2687W v3, 128GB Ram). The machine works fine with the default drivers.

Switching to Nvidia proprietary drivers (352.63) and restarting causes odd screen refresh behavior:

1. If you click anywhere, the screen doesn't update. e.g. you click on oocalc, nothing happens.
2. You do ctrl-alt-f1 then ctrl-alt-f7, the screen now shows the current state (e.g. oocalc is now open), but nothing you do refreshes the screen anymore.
3. Some weird glitches show up. Sometimes white rectangles appear randomly... etc. Please see attached photo:

   [image]

Any idea what's going on? How can I fix this? Thanks and have a great weekend.

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/684028/37165) had asked for Nvidia Titan X driver, which has an answer suggesting to install latest driver (`nvidia-352` is the recommended stable, but *not* latest).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.
But when there are problems with the drivers - and you are having problems ...
then you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA.
This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on "NVIDIA power cards".

Remove the currently installed drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest official stable drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```